# I have a points and I need to find the function

Tags: functions

I have these points:

```
(1,      256071764)
(6,      71020138)
(1469,   582701)
(1550,   421823)
(50752,  8546)
(65031,  5282)
(94961,  5341)
(411573, 2670)
```

I need to find a function satisfying this like f(x)=.... 
Thank you very much.

Comment: There are infinite functions that go through those points. You need to give more context. The numbers are weird, I take it this is statistics related. That's important context...

Comment: Chebycheff-interpolation should give a good result.

Comment: In the concrete case, hyperbel functions of the form $\frac{c}{x}$ might be a better approach.

Comment: Must the points be hit exactly, or only approximately ?

Comment: The points are exactly, I need the function f(x)=... for find more points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote $(x_i, y_i)$ with $(i=1,2,...,8)$ the 8 points in the main text.

Following the suggestions in the comments, for 8 points $(\ln x_i, \ln y_i)$, we may fit with a straight line (using Mathematica for example):

$$\ln y= 19.6533 - 0.947791 \ln x$$

Thus one candidate of the function $f(x)$ that you are searching for is:

$$y(x)= \exp(19.6533 - 0.947791 \ln x)$$

Here is a snapshot $\ln x_i$ vs.\ln y_i$ plot of the data with the resulting fit fucntion.

[image: here the ln-ln plot with the fit fucntion]

Comment: Thanks very much! Is that what I needed! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use a [Fit-Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting). This requires that you have some knowledge about your data. What do you expect the data to be? This defines you the Trial-Function, and your free parameters which will be optimized. You will get a $\chi^2$-value, which tells you the quality of the fit.

Another method is to use [Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation), which will find a (polynomial) function that goes through all off your data-points.

If you explain better what you want, you might get better answers here.

Comment: I need the function f(x)=... for find more points, but I don't know how...

Comment: Do you require that your function f(x) goes exactly through all of your data-points, or do you want a nice function that is approximatively defined by the data-points. If thats the case, you can use Interpolation (see the link I posted). The second option (fitting) requires you to have previous knowledge about your data-points (like their distribution).

Answer (score 0):

Your question, as it stands, has infinitely many solutions that we can't distinguish unless you explain what you have in mind. Just plot your points, pick a pen and connect them with straight lines; then draw *any* function on the left of the first point and on the right of the last point. Et voilà, you have a function!

Interpolation is useful only if you have some additional constraints. Consider the three points $(0,1)$, $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$. The constant function $x \mapsto 1$ interpolates them, but you can also change it arbitrarily for $x<0$ and $x>2$. Which interpolating function should you choose? The answer usually comes from concrete expectations.